# Write 2-d array as columns of different types

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have four lists `(int, float, float, str)`. But where I create a `2-d numpy array` they write as `"numpy.str_"`:

```
bus_log = np.array([unix_datatime, x, y, bus_number]).transpose()
print(type(bus_log[0][0]))
```

Result:

```
<class 'numpy.str_'>
```

I don't know how to do this. I tried to change types but it didn't help.

Comment: You could make a 1d structured array with that data.  The dtype would specify 4 fields.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the resulting NumPy array will have one common type for the whole array if written this way:

```
bus_log = np.array([unix_datatime, x, y, bus_number]).transpose()
```

Numpy will end up casting everything to a string, because of NumPy's casting rules. You can see the array type with `bus_log.dtype` property.

You can create a NumPy array with mixed types this way:

```
a = np.zeros((1,1), dtype=[('unixtime', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'),\
     ('bus_number', '|S20')])
a[0] = (unix_datatime, x, y, bus_number)
```

Comment: When I run this, I delievered error: a[0] = [unix_datatime, x, y, bus_number]
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 1

Comment: Yes, it should have been a tuple instead of a list. Fixed now.

Comment: Now i have new error message: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Strange, I works here. I'm using Python 2.7. Another thing is that you might just want to leave the strings out of the array, that would make everything much easier. Why do you want to store strings in the array? You could maybe keep the on the side in a list?

Comment: I am using a fucntions, what have only ndarray.